# Uninstall OSX 10.10 without Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos

I have installed the OSX 10.10, and the update 10.10.1, and nothing I do can make my Photoshop function. (CS3) I wish, therefore, to uninstall Yosemite 10.10. However, I have never set up Time Machine. Can I do this?

Comment: What kind of Mac do you have? Did it come with an OS on DVD?

Comment: You might have to completely wipe the hard drive to get off 10.10, so a Back up is strongly advisable to keep your stuff.